# program succeded in no error but this method is not working

Tags: c#

```
class game_rule
{
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        Form1 prgBar = new Form1();
        prgBar.progressBar1.Increment(-200);
        SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
    }
}
```

But this code below (from form1-direct) working.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  game_rule dt = new game_rule();
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    progressBar1.Increment(-200); // this is work
    dt.DoAttack(); // this is not work... but there is no build error at all!
  }
}
```

question edited:
`form form1 "progressBar1.Increment(-200);"` is working while `prgBar.progressBar1.Increment(-200);` from class game_rule is not, which is "dt.DoAttack();"

Comment: this is work or this is not work - this is the question. It's really hard to understand Your question.

Comment: Rewrite your question in a manner we can all understand, what's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I am question poster = `Application.Run(new Form1());` this is program.cs

Comment: I am questino poster = I just tested `prgBar.progressBar4.Increment(-200);` cause build error... because Form1 only have progressBar1, 2, 3 controls... it makes me still wondering why `prgBar.progressBar1.Increment(-200);` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prgBar.Show()`

Is this what you need? Did you forget to show the new form?

EDIT:

*I'm answering to you comment...*

you need a static property to access the form from somewhere else:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  // This is you constructor (not shown in your sample code).
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Instance = this;
  }

  public static Form1 Instance { get; private set;}

  game_rule dt = new game_rule();
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    progressBar1.Increment(-200); // this is work
    dt.DoAttack(); // this is not work... but there is no build error at all!
  }
}


class game_rule
{
    public void DoAttack()
    {
        Form1.Instance.progressBar1.Increment(-200);
        SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
    }
}
```

or another approach could be by dependency injection (not a perfect one but it's a good beginning):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

  game_rule dt = new game_rule();
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    progressBar1.Increment(-200); // this is work
    dt.DoAttack(this); // this is not work... but there is no build error at all!
  }
}


class game_rule
{        
    public void DoAttack(Form1 form)
    {
        form1.progressBar1.Increment(-200);
        SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, my progressBar1, 2, 3 controls are in the form1... and I am trying to access it from game_rule class

Comment: You created a new form that's why it did not work. It is gramatically corect in c# but logically not :-)